# Bitrix - Can I change $arResult array from a file where it is created

Tags: bitrix

I am working on some changes in CRM > Deal section. I want to make some changes in $arresult[] array for some form validation. It takes a ready made input tag in field array. But I want to know in which file this variable $arresult[] is created?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$arResult is created in the corresponding component. In your case it would be `crm.deal.edit` or `crm.deal.list`. These system components are located in `/bitrix/components/bitrix/`.

You should not modify "core" components anyway. If you want to somehow modify $arResult either create your own component (copy to `/bitrix/components/YOUR_NAMESPACE/` or use `result_modifier.php` in the component's template.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it and found the solution.